# Regex to differentiate thousand separated number vs not thousand separated number

Tags: java, regex, text, text-processing

I need to extract a price information in a given text line. So far I was successful with below regex `(\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?)` in java with lines like `price will be 90,500 USD`

But, now I also have lines having another number before the price start `(eg: for order number 12345 the price will be 100,500 USD)`. In this case my price extraction fails. For example, above will give me `123` as the result.

Can I have a regex/another way to extract only the price information regardless another number is present or not? (price will be always thousand separated with or without decimal points)

below is the full code I am using right now for this work:

```java
private String getPrice(String fileText) {
    String lines[] = fileText.split(System.lineSeparator());

    for (String line : lines) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            return m.group(0);
        }

        p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?)");
        m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            return m.group(0);
        }   
    }       
    return "";
}
```

I expect the match to be in word level. `(eg: 123 of 12345 should not match.)` My word separator is `space` only. `123-456` is considered a single word. So out of `123456`, `123-456`, `123,456`, `123,456.56`, `A123456` only `123,456`, `123,456.56` should match. The problem is my current code extracts `123` of `123456`, `123-456` and `A123456`

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile(".*\\D(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?)")` to get the last match. Return `m.group(1)`

Comment: Or add the currency after the price `(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?) USD\\b` as you are using a capturing group for the price. https://regex101.com/r/xTJBeX/1

Comment: Yes, so the question is, how to determine it is the price you need?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Using currency code is not possible since this is for many currencies. Sometimes they write currency code before the price.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew went through many reports, so far I found only the price contains thousand separator. That's what I am planning to use. Other numbers in same line does not contain them in this case.

Comment: So, the extra requirement is *at least 1 comma*, right? `Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+(?:\\.\\d+)?")`? See https://regex101.com/r/mtLNLb/1

Comment: The decimal point is ".". Thousand separator is ",". There can be no commas if value is less than 1000

Comment: @Leni Then how can you describe the *character context* for a valid match? Can you do that? If not, no regex will help you.

Comment: If the number has more than 3 digits it should be comma separated. In my case these additional reference numbers have more than 4 digits.

Comment: So changing the quantifier from `*` to `+` would be a possible solution.

Comment: Also I don't need to match parts of non space separated words. (eg: 741 of 741567, 741 of 741-098 and so on)

Comment: It seems you may  use `Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches the number in any context and the decimal part is obligatory.

I suggest:

- Matching the number only when it is not enclosed with word characters
- Using an optional non-capturing group around the fracion number part pattern.

Use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mtLNLb/2).

The `\b` patterns are word boundaries and `(?:...)?` in `(?:\\.\\d+)?` is a non-capturing group that is repeated one or zero times, i.e. is optional.